# i would like to add data from one document into other cell on a daily basis, is this possible?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

i want to import data from this sheet into another.
where i can add the number of time 'cardboard' appears in the column 'stillage reference' in column D based on the date in column G on a daily basis.

Is this possible?

=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RO31w9R6GVWsxLm8nOPJUJ0T444hHfWH6pyIL7wvT2o/edit#gid=1649976768", ('Stillage Reference'! COUNTIFD:D,"Cardboard")

[image]

Comment: yes this is possible. However, since we are not mind readers, you will need to provide a few more details if you need help on HOW to do this. Lern [ask] then edit your question and provide data sample, desired outcome, logic in words, what you have tried.

Comment: i have updated made my question made it clearer, can  you assist? thanks.

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows Google Sheets, not Excel. These are not the same software and they have different functionality. Please tag your question properly, i.e. with the software you are actually using.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've read [ask] or my first comment. I'm sorry, but if you cannot follow simple instructions, then it's really hard to help you.

Comment: ive tried to explain my problem. Nevermind.